# Python: Assigning values to 2D-array elements

Tags: python

I created a 2x2 2D-array of 0's as follows:

```
sizes=[[0]*2]*2

sizes
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

I want to change the second element of the first row to 1. I do this as follows:

```
sizes[0][1]=1
```

Unfortunately, the second element of the *second* row also changes to 1.

```
sizes
[[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Have a look at the description/hove of tag  python: [Programming questions are off-topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. (There are "no" arrays in Python: you show *list*s. Roughly, *sequence \* int* means *sequence* repeated *int* times - while the result with *immutable*s is unsurprising, with *object*s it means *referring to the same object in multiple places*, with consequences as shown. (The object in question being a list with one nesting level less.))

Comment: The two `[0, 0]` are "shallow copies", i.e. twice the same object.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of how you created the array.

I won't get into too much detail, but if you are familiar with the concept of "pointers", then an array is just a pointer - copying it will copy the pointer, so changing at one "clone" will change the other. Here you have copied your array twice.

To fix this, consider writing it in this form instead: `[[0, 0] for _ in range(2)]` which will create two brand-new lists and combine them - instead of copying the same one twice.

Comment: Thank you so much!